# How to create ViewModel from local json with swift higher order function in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, jsondecoder

I've a local json and created data model which can parse and get data, I wanted to create a view model from data model to use in the view controller can any suggest how to to with swift higher order functions.

JSON:

```
{
    "segment": {
        "user1": {
            "banners": {
                "order": 1,
                "items": [1, 3, 4]
            },
            "products": {
                "order": 2,
                "items": [1, 2, 3, 4]
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "banners": {
                "order": 2,
                "items": [4, 3]
            },
            "products": {
                "order": 1,
                "items": [2, 3, 4]
            }
        }
    },
    "productsList": [{
        "productId": 1,
        "title": "Title of the product",
        "description": "Desciprtion of the product"
    }, {
        "productId": 2,
        "title": "Title of the product",
        "description": "Desciprtion of the product"
    }, {
        "productId": 3,
        "title": "Title of the product",
        "description": "Desciprtion of the product"
    }, {
        "productId": 4,
        "title": "Title of the product",
        "description": "Desciprtion of the product"
    }]
}
```

Data Model::

```
struct dataModel : Codable {
    let segment : Segment?
    let productsList : [ProductsList]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case segment = "segment"
        case productsList = "productsList"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        segment = try values.decodeIfPresent(Segment.self, forKey: .segment)
        productsList = try values.decodeIfPresent([ProductsList].self, forKey: .productsList)
    }
}

struct Banners : Codable {
    let order : Int?
    let items : [Int]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case order = "order"
        case items = "items"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        order = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .order)
        items = try values.decodeIfPresent([Int].self, forKey: .items)
    }
}

struct Products : Codable {
    let order : Int?
    let items : [Int]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case order = "order"
        case items = "items"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        order = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .order)
        items = try values.decodeIfPresent([Int].self, forKey: .items)
    }
}

struct ProductsList : Codable {
    let productId : Int?
    let title : String?
    let description : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productId = "productId"
        case title = "title"
        case description = "description"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        productId = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .productId)
        title = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
    }
}

struct Segment : Codable {
    let user1 : User1?
    let user2 : User1?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user1 = "user1"
        case user2 = "user2"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user1 = try values.decodeIfPresent(User1.self, forKey: .user1)
        user2 = try values.decodeIfPresent(User1.self, forKey: .user2)
    }
}

struct User1 : Codable {
    let banners : Banners?
    let products : Products?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case banners = "banners"
        case products = "products"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        banners = try values.decodeIfPresent(Banners.self, forKey: .banners)
        products = try values.decodeIfPresent(Products.self, forKey: .products)
    }
}
```

In the view model require an array of sections for each user with below conditions.

1. sections must place based on **order** key in the json for example if order is 1 then it should be first element in user array and 2 in the sense it should be second element in the user array.
2. **items** array represents **productId** in the productsList array, If the items array has 3 then in the user array it should append **prodouctId:3**.

With the above two conditions how can I create two array for user1 and and user2. As per above json for example it should return as below.

```
user1 = [<banners items products>, <products items products>] //Based on order key sorting in array.

user2 = [< products items products>, < banners items products>] //Based on order key sorting in array.
```

Created ViewModel as below can call viewModel from viewDidLoad and it should return data for each user. Can anyone suggest proper way of doing this with above conditions I spent lot of time to do it wasn't working as expected.

```
struct viewModel {
    func getUser1Data() -> []{ ///As per json should return banners items as first element and then products items
        
    }
    func getUser2Data() -> [] { ///As per json should return products items as first element and then banners items
        
    }
}

struct User {
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
}
```

Function to fetch and parse json.

```
  func getModelFromJson(fileName: String) -> dataModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        do {
            let result = try decoder.decode(dataModel.self, from: data!)
            return result
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Are there only ever two users?

Comment: Yeah there will be users only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (notes in the code)... I don't know why you mentioned higher order functions, I don't see any reason to use one here...

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let segment: Segment
    let productsList: [ProductsList]
}

struct ProductsList: Codable {
    let productId: Int
    let title: String
    let description: String
}

struct Segment: Codable {
    let user1: User
    let user2: User
}

struct User: Codable {
    let banners: BannersProducts
    let products: BannersProducts

    // return items that are sorted the way you want.
    var items: [Int] {
        [banners, products]
            .sorted(by: { $0.order < $1.order })
            .flatMap { $0.items }
    }
}

// one type for both Banners and Products
struct BannersProducts: Codable {
    let order: Int
    let items: [Int]
}

func getUsersFromJson(fileName: String) -> (user1: [ProductsList], user2: [ProductsList]) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let response = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    // put the products in a dictionary for easy lookup
    let products = Dictionary(grouping: response.productsList, by: { $0.productId })
    let user1 = response.segment.user1.items.map { products[$0]!.first! } // user1 products
    let user2 = response.segment.user2.items.map { products[$0]!.first! }// user2 products
    return (user1, user2)
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary(grouping: response.productsList, by: \.productId)`

Comment: Thank you I made some changes to it based on your idea it works as expected.

Comment: Agreed. The Codeable protocol removes a lot of the legwork in parsing though may not be exhaustive.